# How to cut a string till first numerical value appears using regex

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, cut

I am trying to write a script which can extract the words from a string untill the first number appears.

ex :- I have a file named as `typed-list-4.1.3.Final.jar` and I want the output as:-  `typed-list.jar`

Since all the files have different names, but, they end with a version number and `.jar` extension so I was trying to `sed` the part from where the first number appears and then append `.jar`.

My files look like :- 
`log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar, hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar` etc

I tried to use `sed` command like this but it's not working :-

`sed -i 's/-[0-9]*$//g' test1.sh`      --- where `test1.sh` contains this string "`typed-list-4.1.3.Final.jar`"

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
sed 's/-\([0-9]\+\.\)\+[0-9]\+.*\.jar/.jar/' Input_file
```

Results for the provided inputs:

```
typed-list.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl.jar
hibernate-core.jar
```

The regex matches with a substring such as:

- starting with a dash `-`
- pattern repetition of digit(s) dot digit(s) ...
- some other substring in between (such as `Final`)
- ends with the extension `.jar`

Then the `sed` command replaces the matched substring with just the extension.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Gouri I've added some explanations in my answer. Also I've modified my `sed` command  considering the case the version numbers contain more than one digit. BR.

Answer (score 0):

Sed:

```
sed -E 's/(.*)-([[:digit:]]+\.){2}[[:digit:]]+.*(\.[^.]+)$/\1\3/' dat
```

```
log4j-slf4j-impl.jar
hibernate-core.jar
typed-list.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo typed-list-4.1.3.Final.jar | awk  'sub(/-4.{10}/,"",$0)'
typed-list.jar
```